# simulate \item in (adaptive) tabular in a tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tcolorbox

I'm trying to create a layout for multiple choice questions using tcolorbox. Some questions come with an image.
I was thinking of a layout where the question is in the upper part of the tcolorbox, while the lower part contains a tabular with the answers and the figure.
I'm almost there, but there are two aspects I would like to fix.

1. some of the answers written in the cells of the tabular might be kind of long, so I'd like to adapt the column width to their length, so that they do not "wrap".
2. sometimes the answers are really too long, and wrapping cannot be avoided. If that is the case, I'd like the "tick box" to behave like a bullet in an itemized list (that is, the whole answer should be properly hanging from it).

I tried several solutions, but I cannot seem to get what I want.
Here is what I accomplished so far

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\tcbset{enhanced,colframe=black!35,beforeafter skip=10pt,boxsep=0mm,left=1mm,right=1mm,sidebyside gap=3mm,top=3mm,bottom=2mm,boxrule=0.25mm} 

\begin{document}


% first tcolorbox. -------------
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[2][4]
\tcblower
\tcbsidebyside[sidebyside adapt=right, blanker,sidebyside gap=2mm,
]{% 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
$\Box$  answer  \hfill   & \hangindent=0.55cm $\Box$ answer  \vfill  \\
$\Box$ answer  & \hangindent=0.55cm $\Box$  this
answer is much longer than the others blah
\end{tabularx}


}{% 
\resizebox{0.25\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill=yellow,draw=yellow!75!red] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
\end{tcolorbox}

% second tcolorbox. -------------
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[3][2]
\tcblower
\tcbsidebyside[sidebyside adapt=right, blanker,sidebyside gap=2mm,
]{% 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
\hangindent=0.5cm $\Box$  this
answer is much longer than the others blah    & \hangindent=0.55cm $\Box$ answer \hfill   \\
$\Box$ answer  & \hangindent=0.55cm $\Box$ answer \hfill 
\end{tabularx}
}{% 
\resizebox{0.25\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[fill=yellow] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

I used `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}`
or I used `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}` to adapt the tabularx column to its content. However, I have no way of knowing whether a long answer will be in the first or second column, because the answers are shuffled at each different instance of the question.

I used `\hangindent=0.5cm` to "align" the "bullet" box, but the result is uneven... For instance the distance between the box and the first word in the answer is not the same if the answer is short (less than one line).

I thought of using a table with one single row and two columns, and placing the answers in one itemized list per column.
However I think that itemized lists can be placed only inside "p" columns, whereas the adaptive width seems to rely on "X" columns.

Apologies for my English, and thank you for any insight.
Francesco